# How to solve this using genetic algorithm?

Tags: resources, scheduling, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I need suggestions for solving the following optimization problem

1. I have N jobs, J1,J2,J3,J4... JN.
2. I have n persons to finish the above jobs. P1,P2,P3....Pn
3. I have some constraints like only specific persons can do certain jobs. For example P1 can do only J1,J4,J5, P2 can do only J2,J7,J14,J8,J9 etc
4. The persons are available for certain periods of time of day. Like P1 available for 9am to 11am and then 12 noon to 3pm and then 3:30pm to 6pm. Like that applicable for other persons have their available times.
5. The traveling time also need to be considered based on the job locations and current location of persons.

So ultimately the genetic algorithm need to provide an optimum solution in form of a schedule. The following diagram shows below

[image]

Comment: "So ultimately the genetic algorithm need to provide an optimum solution" -- a GA is the wrong tool if you expect an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

On first sight, it looks like [Project Job Scheduling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c), which is a form of *Job Shop Scheduling*. The Mista2013 competition featured that problem and several papers describe several implementations for that.

But a closer look reveals that this is more of a [Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg) (*VRPTW*), for which there also many papers available too.